# Show opencv video frames in widget QT5 c++

Tags: opencv, qt5

I want to display a video read with OpenCV in a qt widget.I have already read the frames (have function that reads frames) but don't know how to show them. I need to show the video in a little widget in a window.

Please share a code that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, you should play video in a Qlabel. this link might help you about Qlabel: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlabel.html
at first create a label and then can play your video in while(1) loop; dont forgot that input shape of the image in Qlabel is QPixmap but shape of image in openCV is Mat; so you have to convet image shape from Mat to QPixmap.
for this you can convert mat to QImage and then you can convet QPixmap to QImage in Qt.
I hope you will realize it when you read code and its comments.

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("String Video Address");
if(!cap.isOpened())
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", "error: Video not loaded "); // show error message
cv::Mat cvframe;
QImage Qframe;
while(1){
    cap >> cvframe;
    if (cvframe.empty())
        break;
    Qframe = convertOpenCVMatToQtQImage(cvframe);
    ui->Video_lable->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Qframe)); // show images on form labels
    ui->Video_lable->setScaledContents( true );
    ui->Video_lable->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored );
    char c=(char)cv::waitKey(25); // waits to display frame
    if(c==27)
        break;
}
//The function that convert OpenCVMat To QtQImageQImage
QImage MainWindow::convertOpenCVMatToQtQImage(cv::Mat mat)
{
    if(mat.channels() == 1) { // if 1 channel (grayscale or black and white) image
        return QImage((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);// return QImage
    }
    else if(mat.channels() == 3) { // if 3 channel color image
        cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);// flip colors
        return QImage((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);// return QImage
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "in convertOpenCVMatToQtQImage, image was not 1 channel or 3 channel, should never get here";
    }
    return QImage();// return a blank QImage if the above did not work
}
```